# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method resolution

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm having some problems with error messages in Groovy.

I was making a relatively simple call in my set-up script, like:

```
def count = 0
//Currently unused
//tarStep = runner.getTestStepByName("Setup and Check")
//def check = tarStep.getPropertyValue("fileCheck")
while(count < 5)
{
     //if(check == true)
     runner.gotoStepByName("PRequest1")
     count++
}
```

And I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.MockTestSuiteRunner.gotoStepByName() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [PRequest1]
```

A similar error happens when I uncomment the code "runner.getTestStepByName":

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.MockTestSuiteRunner.getTestStepByName() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Setup and Check]
```

I'm not sure why those errors appear. I looked at some other [questions about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128003/groovy-lang-missingmethodexception-no-signature-of-method) [MissingMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411209/how-to-fix-groovy-lang-missingmethodexception-no-signature-of-method) but even though the problem is the same the answers don't apply to my errors.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. How do I resolve the MissingMethodException?

Comment: Show what you set runner equal to.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/panels/support/MockTestSuiteRunner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `runner` is of the wrong class.  It looks like you need a [`MockTestRunner`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/panels/support/MockTestRunner.html), rather than a [`MockTestSuiteRunner`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/panels/support/MockTestSuiteRunner.html).  The `MockTestRunner` is the one with the [`gotoStepByName`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/panels/support/MockTestRunner.html#gotoStepByName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: You're right! I had been looking at the wrong class. I knew it was something simple, but now I feel kind of stupid. xD Thank you!